# rails 3.1 date validation - is acts_like_date? enough or even necessary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date

I'm trying to create a custom date validation to prevent SQL injection (since rails does not provide one and I would rather understand what's going on than rely on a gem for something as basic as this).

Two questions:

1) Is it necessary to validate a date since rails seems to automatically convert date input into a date object. In the console, invalid dates do not save.

2) If it is necessary, is value.acts_like_date? enough to validate, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

All data rails processes from the client side is automatically escaped (by default) since rails 3.0.  If protecting against SQL injection is your goal you should be golden without writing any specific validations for it.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection